# Implement real time features into a symfony2 application? (live dashboard)

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, symfony, socket.io

I have a symfony2 app what stores data in MySql. It's a simple app, I mainly use just php.

In the app there are some administrators and they got a dashboard where they see every activity in the app. You have to refresh the page to see the new activities.

Now I have to make the dashboard real time.

There are some event specific notifications, for example you push a red button on your panel, and in 3 days you have to push it again. If 3 days past and you didn't push it, the administrator who is watching the dashboard now instantly get a notification. The other admins see it too after they watch the dashboard.

And there is the "real real-time" things, you push a blue button on the website and every administrator instantly get a notification on their dashboard, no time delay.

I never worked with real time apps before, so I read a bit in the topic.
I read about pubnub (and its brothers),socket.io and node.js but I'm not sure abou the most efficent model.

Pubnub have SDKs for PHP and socket.io, so I think I can do the real time part, but have no idea how to start the time specific notifications.

On the other hand, maybe I should go with the node.js, and do a long pooling solution, so I constantly read my MySql server with node and push notifications to Socket.io ,but I'm not sure countinously read my database is a good idea.

I know php is not really the language for deamons, I know nothing how it's going with node.

I'm not really asking for code, but for logic, how could I implement this in a smart and efficent way?

Comment: Check out: http://socketo.me/. Simple websocket integration into symfony. For efficiency, use a web socket if you can. Polling will get expensive very fast depending on the traffic.

Comment: @phpisuber01 Looks nice, have experience with it in production? Still I don't knw to to send time based messages, I guess I have to run a daemon somehow.

Comment: No experience yet, still in development with it. Why not use a cron job? No need to be complicated, it not be accurate to the second but within a few minutes depending on your configuration.